# how to get a relationship value in form_builder in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Product and Category table. Category `has_many` Product and Product `belongs_to` Category

When I work in console sandbox i can easily get the category a product belongs to by doing:

```
@p = Product.find(29)
@p.category
```

However, in the edit page of the Product I am not able to get the category it belongs to.

```
<% form_for :product, @products do |p| %>
   <%= p.error_messages %>
   <td><%=label "category", "Category"%></td>
   <td><%=p.select :category_id, options_for_select(
          @categories.map {|s| [s.name, s.id]}, 
          ["#{p.category.id}"])%></td>
```

So basically i am trying to have edit page for a product with a drop down that contains all categories but i want the current category preselected.

Error I get is:

```
undefined method `category' for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0xbb35f64>
```

Answer (score 11):

`p` holds a form builder object, not your model instance. To access the model instance do this:

```
... ["#{p.object.category.id}"])%></td>
```

Note the "object".

**Explanation:** `p` within the block scope of `form_for` is **not** your product, so it is **not** of type `#<Product>`. Instead it is a `#<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0xbb35f64>` as the error message tells you. Thus it knows nothing about your model's properties. A `FormBuilder` holds your form object in its `object` method.

A FormBuilder holds other cool tools which may be useful. I suggest to do a `<%= debug p %>` to find out more.

Comment: so in ruby. calling object brings back the actual object?

Comment: No, "object" is a method on the form builder instance which returns the associated model instance you applied the form to. BTW: Fix your label also, call <%= p.label :category %>.